# Linux device driver module compilation using gcc

Tags: linux, gcc, linux-device-driver

I have a basic linux device driver module :

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>   
#include <linux/kernel.h>

static int __init hello_init(void)
{
printk(KERN_ALERT "Hello, world \n");
return 0;
}

static void __exit hello_exit(void)
{
printk(KERN_ALERT "Goodbye, world \n");
}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);
```

I am able to compile this module in traditional way which is by using a simple Makefile which uses obj-m , but I want to compile this using command line gcc. This is because I can use gcc -save-temps flag to see the intermediate generated files(this can be particularly helpful to understand as Linux kernel uses lot of preprocessor stuff).

So is there a way to compile using command line gcc ??

**EDIT** Attaching the Makefile I have used

```
ifeq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)
    KERNELDIR ?= /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
    PWD := $(shell pwd)

EXTRA_CFLAGS+= -save-temps

modules:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) modules

modules_install:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) modules_install

clean:
    rm -rf *.o *~ core .depend .*.cmd *.ko *.mod.c .tmp_versions

.PHONY: modules modules_install clean

else

    obj-m := hello.o
endif
```

Comment: Using `gcc` from the command line successfully depends on setting up the shell environment properly.  That is (partly) what `make` and `Makefile` are for.  If you really insist on using the shell, then you should append your `Makefile` to your question for review.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try to add "EXTRA_CFLAGS" in your module's Makefile?
such as EXTRA_CFLAGS += -save-temps

Hope it help you!

Comment: Tried with your suggestion Did not work :( it executes correctly in the sense .o file is generated but I am not able to see the intermediate files(.i etc) and I have tried some variations of the suggestion which you told but no luck :(

Comment: @LeoMessi -- Exactly what did you try? Using a variable such as `EXTRA_CFLAGS` or just `CFLAGS` is the tried and true way to customize the compile rule in Makefiles. Did you just define the variable, and forget to insert the variable in the compile rule? (The answer is **incomplete** in that regard.)

Comment: @sawdust : I have edited the post to attach the Makefile I tried.Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to to that directly in Makefile, but you can generate your *.i* file by file. From the root directory of the Linux kernel source:

```
make drivers/media/pci/sta2x11/sta2x11_vip.i
```

This will generate the *.i* file. To generate your module source file (which is outside the kernel tree) just use the absolute path to it:

```
make /path/to/hello.i
```

It should work